# Role of preacher in Sympathy for Lady Vengeance

Tags: sympathy-lady-vengeance

When we learn about the life of Geum-ja there is no mention of the preacher, it seems as though she only met him after her release from prison.

Is the role of the preacher only a gimmick to move the plot along? Being an American viewer of a foreign movie though I was wondering if something was lost on me.

Or could it have been from the reputation she developed in prison of being an "Angel" that attracted his attention?

Comment: ["She has been released from prison, now in her early 30s, and over this long time has amassed a new reputation: that of saintly conversion to Christianity. She is a veritable modern Magdalene whose purity surrounds her like an aura."](http://www.theguardian.com/culture/2006/feb/10/8)

Comment: I see - that answers the question.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Change your comment to an answer paraphrasing the article and I will accept it if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so much a gimmick, but simply the first indication that [prison didn't "fix" her](http://www.theguardian.com/culture/2006/feb/10/8):

> Lee Yeong-ae plays Geum-ja, a delicately beautiful young woman who 13
>   years previously astonished the nation by confessing to a horrendous
>   crime: the kidnap and murder of a five-year-old child. She has been
>   released from prison, now in her early 30s, and over this long time
>   has amassed a new reputation: that of saintly conversion to
>   Christianity. She is a veritable modern Magdalene whose purity
>   surrounds her like an aura. But Geum-ja has a secret - a secret from
>   the news media, from her fellow prisoners and from us, the audience.
>   And the secret begins to unfold when an evangelical Christian group is
>   coldly rebuffed when they greet her at the jail gates with a
>   tambourine-rattling hymn.

Only later we learn the reality about her stay in prison, how she started planning her revenge and made allies.